# How can I configure zsh to autocomplete branch names while using 'git checkout'?

Tags: git, autocomplete, zsh

When I say 'git checkout ' I want zsh to autocomplete names of my git branches. Is that possible?

Answer (score 13):

I got git autocomplete to work in zsh by adding this to my `.zshrc`:

```
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67627099/480608

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way (and probably the only one not requiring a serious amount of hacking) is to update zsh. On my `zsh 4.3.9` autocompletion works for git branches.

Comment: I'm on zsh 4.3.11 and autocompletion doesn't work for me...using latest git as well.

Comment: You might need to enable it - look for ' git' in the `zshcontrib` manpage.