# zsh git autocomplete: __git_find_on_cmdline error

Tags: git, zsh

I am trying to get git autocomplete working with zsh and am running into a weird error (even though the autocomplete appears to complete successfully):

Installation:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/.zsh
cd ~/.zsh
curl -o git-completion.bash https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
curl -o _git https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh
```

Added to `~/.zshrc`:

```bash
zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*' script ~/.zsh/git-completion.bash
fpath=(~/.zsh $fpath)

autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```

I open a new shell and run `git checkout` + "ty" + <kbd>tab</kbd> and I expect it to autocomplete with "typescript" with no errors:

```bash
raine[npm-check-updates]% gc ty__git_find_on_cmdline:[:7: unknown condition: -lt                                    ✓
__git_find_on_cmdline:[:7: unknown condition: -lt
__git_find_on_cmdline:[:7: unknown condition: -lt
pescript
```

It does autocomplete to "typescript" but with an error in between, right where I hit tab. What is causing this and how do I make it go away?

Comment: `script ~/.zsh/git-completion.bash` Bash completion in zsh? Shouldn't it also be zsh completion?

Comment: The bash completion scripts are not always zsh-compatible. There's ongoing work to fix this up, but when they don't work, it just means someone missed something. You can use bash instead of zsh, or use the zsh scripts, or participate in the ongoing work, or whatever you like, here.

Comment: @raine-revere Do you think you could Accept my answer?

Comment: @Marlon It's already accepted. It was accepted on May 21, 2021.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I don’t know how I missed that. 

Comment: Too much coding? Hehe j/k

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Zsh ships with excellent Git completion out of the box](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Zsh). Just throw everything you posted away, except this:

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

Then it'll work just fine.